# SQL - Print sum of select contents in a column

Tags: sql, sum, unique-values

This is to PRINT, from dbo.Emp, the total number of records, per unique value

I did it this way:
    SELECT field1, COUNT(*) records
    FROM dbo.Emp
    GROUP BY field1
    HAVING SUM(*)

Comment: Alright. So, would that PRINT the total number  per 'unique' or distinct value? Something like COUNT(Distinct)records or COUNT (SUM of distinct)records

Comment: If you want distinct use count( distinct field1)

Comment: AH...YES! THANK YOU Radar   So: SELECT COUNT(Distinct field1) records
FROM Emp
GROUP BY field1